# I want an arrayed object to be upright throughout a tapered spiral

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

[image: image description xDXDXddxdxxdoneone!!!one]

I want all of the objects to stay upright and un-distorted throughout the whole structure.

Also if you notice anything fucky with what I'm doing and have suggestions I'm all ears. I am new to this and need to learn the proper workflow the first time as to not spend a lot of time unlearning bad habits.

Thanks!

---

I have followed what you said and now I'm getting 180 degree rotation on the y axis.[image: 180 deg rotation]

Also there is only one object at the very top that has a random amount of rotation. [image: wacky at the top]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're doing anything funky..

The simplest way I can think of to persuade Blender to  respect the Normal, but ignore the Tangents of your curve is as follows:

- In its Data tab > Shape panel, set the curve's Twist Method to 'Z Up'
- Just as you have already, make a planar object, and give it array and curve modifiers:

[image]

- As before, it tilts, but we're going to use it as a particle emitter, so it won't matter
- Give this placeholder/emitter a Particle System with settings as follows:

[image]

- All particles are emitted on frame 1
- The same number of particles as the array count, evenly distributed, 1 per face.

And: ( my rendered object is called 'Mount')...

[image]

- ... emitting instances of your actual object, aligned to the emitter's Normal (but not its tangent axes)
- The emitter planes are not shown in the final render... In my build, the viewport display sometimes needs kicking to refresh.. moving the current frame off 1 and back again does the trick.

This picture of the result also shows the working orientation of the green rendered mesh, with respect to its own object's local axes.. (adjust in Edit Mode)

[image]

Comment: To be fair, 'funky' wasn't the chosem adjective

Comment: Hey your post has been pretty helpful. but i have run into further issues. I dont know how to put images in the comments so i just put them in the parent post.

Thanks!

Comment: Also is it possible to make the particles into a real object that can be used for physics simulations? I eventually want to have fluid interact with them.

Comment: @hghfhgghg    To make particles real, apply the particle system modifier .. How did you construct your spiral?

Comment: I made the spiral by using a spiral generator addon called "extra shapes"